# How do I configure Kubernetes Ingress controller to support two services?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have two services, web-service is running on port 80 and admin-service is running on port 8000. I'd like all http /admin requests to be proxied to admin-service:8000 and all other requests to go to web-service:80. I've tried the configuration below but it doesn't seem to work. I'm also using Google Kubernetes Engine.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.org/redirect-to-https: "True"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /admin
        backend:
          serviceName: admin-service
          servicePort: 8000
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

looks good, but... does your admin service respond to `GET /admin` ? cause unless you use `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` annotation on your ingress, you need to support the URI in your backing service

Answer (score 0):

The way to specify default backend is outside the `rules`.

I think you should take the web service outside the rule section as specified here: [name-based-virtual-hosting](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting) (look for "Default Backends")

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.org/redirect-to-https: "True"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-secret
  backend:
    serviceName: web-service
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /admin
        backend:
          serviceName: admin-service
          servicePort: 8000
```